# pretty printing OCaml for windows

Tags: windows, ocaml, pretty-print

I knew there is a library for pretty printer using camlp5 in Linux.

Is there anything similar for Windows? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can build `ocaml` and `camlp5` under windows, using `MinGW` and `MSYS`.

There are even binary distributions, ready for use [here](http://caml.inria.fr/download.en.html).

Comment: it's only for the ocaml, right? or is there any camlp5 somewhere there?

Comment: camlp5 is not included in those builds, only camlp4 is. However, once ocaml installed, you can build camlp5 from source under windows.